# Using placeholder template in core data without saving the placeholders?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, partials

I am wondering if its possible to have a core data and use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display template holders; without saving the placeholder template holder to core data.

I am writing an app where a table view will have the following characteristics

1. Maximum amount of rows (ie: 8)
2. Each cell uses a partial view, a single table cell instance with clickable buttons;

[image: Partial view: single table cell instance]

3. A user clicking on the buttons replaces the content for each button
4. When a user comes to save the data it stores the content in the exact places, but **crucially** it should not save the blank placeholder state; but still respect the placement positioning.

> IE: Lets say a user picks the right button for cell 1 and saves it;
>   when the the user returns to this dataset sometime in the future, it
>   should have the imagery and data in the correct place; but still keep
>   the left button for cell 1 empty (placeholder)

The reason I don't want to save the placeholder content is because I consider this data to be "dirty"; its meaningless and has no place in a dataset; **its a view**; not data.

Currently:

1. I create data using `insertInManagedObjectContext` but do not save it until the user has pressed save.
2. Each matchRow has many fighters.  This relationship is a `NSOrderedSet`, managed by core data.

The problems I'm having are;

1. `NSFetchedResultsController` only respects saved core data items; and ignores the placeholder data.
2. If a user only saves one (right button) data, the `NSOrderedSet` sees this as the first (left button) data; which is in correct
3. If I strip out all the placeholder structures from the core data in a pre-save action, the effect is that the order the user wanted is now lost and it causes a crash when reloading because the size of the arrays are incorrect.

> Currently the only way around this is to stop using
>   `NSFetchedResultsController` and use a `NSArray`; and put the placeholders into the array too, then save everything, (dirty objects) and all.

I really don't want to do that.  The placeholder content isn't meant to be saved.

I've been reading a [blog post](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/ios-dev/2013/05/11/best-practice-handling-empty-table-views.html) on using separate classes for special cases where he has different data sources; and uses the technique to  separate class for the "empty" case, and to set it as the table view’s datasource when it's empty.

Whilst this is interesting, it only solves it for an empty case; when my requirement is that the partial view should handle all states; empty data and partial data.

One idea I have is that we need another entity between our record and our match rows;

> Match - MatchRowMeta - Fighter

*Not sure what the relationship would be*

where;

```
RowMeta {
record.obj (relationship)
fighters.obj (relationship)
positionID (integer) - which button has been set
}
```

But I don't think this is the best way to do it; it seems expensive and a lot of heavy lifting to do something relatively simple.

Thus, my question:

Is it possible to have a table view made up of template holders; where the structure is saved to core data but none of the empty (dirty) objects are saved; plus `NSFetchedResultsController` will respect the structure; even when its empty or partially empty?

Edit: Added entity diagram

[image: entity diagram]

Comment: Show your current entities. When can a match have more than 2 fighters?

Comment: But it could have less, this is the issue. It needs to handle the edge case of 1 fighter.  The only other way to do it is have 2 relationship objects, one per fighter I guess.

Comment: Also just showing the entities doesn't respect the order of each fighter in the specific partial.  If I save 1 fighter in the right hand side, then save it; when I return the system only sees 1 record and assumes, incorrectly, that it must be the left hand side.

Comment: No, show a picture of the entities and relationships in your model. Yes you want separate relationships or a meta entity.

Comment: Added entity diagram.  I will try a branch with 2 relationship objects instead of the nsorderedset relationship it currently has as an experiment

Comment: You probably are right, a meta entity is needed; the only problem I have is what is the relationship when dealing with a meta entity because as I see it you still have the issue of the relationships being managed by core data as its abstracted away from you